# iptables -A append one or more rules

Tags: firewall, iptables

I was looking at the man page of iptables today and I noticed that the -A description says “Append one **or more** rules to the end of the selected chain”. Does that mean that if I have:

```
iptables -A INPUT {...rule1...}
iptables -A INPUT {...rule2...}
```

it could be simplified to one line?

```
iptables -A INPUT {...rule1; rule2...}
```

I’ve looked around on google and can’t find an example of anyone ever doing this, but it would simply some of my scripts if it’s possible.

Comment: You might want to look at iptables-save and iptables-restore as an alternative approach to adding multiple rules at once https://serverfault.com/questions/980343/insert-multiple-iptables-rules-in-critical-situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only supply one rule definition in one `iptables -A` invocation.

However, if you use an address such as www.example.com that happens to resolve to more than one address, then multiple rules are appended, one for each address.

For example: (fake IPs used...):

```
$ host www.example.com
www.example.com has address 10.1.2.3
www.example.com has address 10.1.2.4
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s www.example.com -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -L INPUT -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 208K  250M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.1.2.3             0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.1.2.4             0.0.0.0/0
```

So now you have inserted more than one rule using one `iptables -A` invocation.

I agree that this is not quite apparent from the manpage description.

Comment: Yes that's the explanation for "one or more" as described in the next sentence in the man page: "When the source and/or destination names resolve to more than one address, a rule will be added for each possible address combination"

Answer (score 2):

No.  1 rule per iptables call.  the "Append" option is in contrast to the "Insert" option.  Append as in... the new rule goes to the end of the list of rules, but Insert adds the rule to the top of the list.

```
iptables -I INPUT {Rule1}
iptables -I INPUT {Rule2}
```

would result in the rules being as follows:

```
{Rule2}
{Rule1}
```

where

```
iptables -A INPUT {Rule1}
iptables -A INPUT {Rule2}
```

would result in

```
{Rule1}
{Rule2}
```

Comment: This is true, however how does this answer the question whether you can add multiple rules with one iptables -A call?

Comment: @wurtel Yes, first two sentences.  Please read.